# Android studio, Chat Udp

Tags: java, android, сокет, udp, chat

Я новичок. решил написать чат приложение. но тут ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибки.

Вот код

```
public static final int PORT = 53;
public Button btn;
public Button btn1;
public EditText txt;
public ListView lview;
public DatagramSocket socket;
public DatagramPacket packet;
public ArrayList<String> list;
public ArrayAdapter adapter;
public InetAddress inet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        inet = getBroadcastAddress();
        socket.setSoTimeout(500);
        socket.connect(inet, PORT);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String data = txt.getText().toString();
            if (data != "") {
                list.add(data);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                lview.setAdapter(adapter);
                try {
                    socket.send(new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            buf = packet.getData();
            data = buf.toString();
            list.add(data);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            lview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}

public InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow
    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

Вот ошибки

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.aidys.p2p.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Всё просто. У вас NPE на 65 строчке.

Comment: Скорее всего из-за networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. Но как это исправить?) я чайник)

Comment: К сожалению помочь вам невозможно пока вы не признаетесь, какая именно строка шестьдесятпятая)

Comment: И поправьте сообщение об ошибке - там множество лишних пробелов)

Comment: socket.send(new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length()));

Comment: Дополните этим вопрос и уточните в нём же, что именно в этой строчке равняется `null`

Comment: Как я уже говорил, у вас скорее всего networkonmainthreadexception, возникающий при попытке доступа в сеть на девайсах с `API>=11`. Но проверить это можете только вы. Возможно у вас это в логи выведено в блоке `try`, где вы инициализируете сокет. Скорее всего там крах и сокет равен null на выходе и в итоге вы имеете его на 65 строке.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за помощь.) Постараюсь исправить. Кажется понял)

Comment: Если у вас получится решить самостоятельно, то вы сможете написать ответ под этим вопросом и тем самым помочь другим людям, которые столкнутся с этой проблемой в будущем)